# Bad instruction NSDATA with gif file Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, nsbundle

Here is the error. As you can see my image is in the top right corner.

All my code is there, I'm not sure what else to show. \

I have been following the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2)

[image: here]

Apologies, I'm not sure how to resize the image

Error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Your `filePath` is most likely nil, which means that this resource couldn't be found. Do a `if let filePath = filePath { }` check first to see if the image really can't be found.

Comment: Be sure to show your code, not simply a screenshot of your code.  It's important to have your source code as plain text for several reasons.  It allows potential answerers to copy & paste into their IDE to look at your problem.  It also helps with search results (and helps in identifying whether or not your question already has an answer elsewhere).  Adding a screenshot as an extra detail is fine, but should not be considered a replacement for copy & pasting your source code in.

Answer (score -2):

Fixed.

Took image outside 'image' folder